# How to save results to file usig putty grep

Tags: grep

I log in by Putty (ssh) to FTP.
Need to find in all files this string `style="position:absolute;top:-8888px;left:-2900px;z-index:0;"`.

If I type:

```
grep 'position:absolute;top:-8888px;'
```

it gave me some results.
Then try to save to a file 'raport.txt' like this:

```
grep 'position:absolute;top:-8888px;' * -R >>raport.txt
```

Permissions are 777.

Grep only creates the file and saves nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried what you said and it is working. Your problem has nothing to do with ssh or putty. Please add a sequence of what you type in your terminal and add `ls -al` command of your current directory.

Comment: Search was too long and finnaly i get "killed" from grep. If i serach folder by folder, grep save to file.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep 'position:absolute;top:-8888px;' * -R >>raport.txt 
                                        ^^
```

It's possible that `grep` isn't searching all of the files that you expect it to, because the `-R` option (search subdirectories recursively) is in the wrong place. For most programs, including grep, options like `-R` should come before the non-option arguments.

In other words, try running it with `-R` at the beginning, like this:

```
grep -R 'position:absolute;top:-8888px;' * >>raport.txt
     ^^
```